# TopologyTestDriver kafka streams. In memory state store only for jUnit tests

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I would like to use in memory state store during jUnit testing, because of multiple issues regarding write accesses locally and in my build pipeline. Is there any way to archive this without touching topology and by only changing properties?

[image]